# Is there a way to produce this division symbol? ÷

Tags: symbols

Is there a way to produce this division symbol?  ÷

The term `\div` gives an error of `Missing $ inserted`.

`\÷` is not working either.

Comment: I guess you have not tried `$\div$`, correct?

Comment: `\div` is a mathematical symbol, so it should be inside a math formula: $6\div 3=2$ should work. If you want to use it in text, do `\usepackage{textcomp}` and use `\textdiv`.

Comment: No, I hadn't tried with dollar signs or with the textcomp package.  Thank you all so very much -- greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Werner's and egreg's comments are correct: you should still use `\div`, but inside of math mode.

So: `$6 \div 3 = 2$`.

[image: $6 \div 3 = 2$]

Comment: @lawlist: your upvote (and check if this the answer you adopt) are thanks enough.

Answer (score 17):

The questioner said: **Is there a way to produce this division symbol? ÷**

And I said:

### With PSTricks

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,4)
    \psline[linewidth=10pt](0,2)(4,2)
    \pscircle*(2,0.75){15pt}
    \pscircle*(2,3.25){15pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### With TikZ

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}(4,4)
    \draw[line width=10pt,fill=black] 
        (0,2) -- (4,2)
        (2,0.75) circle (15pt)
        (2,3.25) circle (15pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Miscellaneous

If you need a fancier div symbol...

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\pstVerb{/ptcm {\pst@number\psunit\space div} bind def}
\makeatother
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,4)
\psclip
{
    \pscustom[dimen=middle]
    {
    \psframe[linewidth=10pt](!0 2 5 ptcm sub)(!4 2 5 ptcm add)
    \moveto(!2 15 ptcm add 0.75)
    \pscircle(2,0.75){15pt}
    \moveto(!2 15 ptcm add 3.25)
    \pscircle(2,3.25){15pt}
    }
}
    \rput(2,2){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems gratuitous to use TikZ or PSTricks to recreate a symbol that is in the basic set of math fonts.  I can't think of any reason to adopt this answer over just `\div`, and worse, it might intimidate a novice user. (As I make this comment I see someone else has already downvoted.)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: It depends on the context of use that has not been clearly defined in the question.

Comment: Can you provide a use case where the TikZ/PSTricks method is preferable?

Comment: It's always nice to have a large bag of tricks, and also to see what is within the realm of possibilities.  Thank you all so very much.

Comment: All: there's no need to further downvote this answer.  The point is made.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents May be write in bold at Starting of Answer **Warning:Overkill solution Don't Use routinely, Only for fun** to make your attempt explicit so that there will be no Downvotes. I did not downvote as i know you are very knowledgeable person :).

Comment: This above solution has the definite weakness of not resizing in sub/scripts and other such situations, in contrast to `\div`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: You are not absolutely wrong. :-)

Comment: I think that is the most down votes I've seen on this site ... You should get a badge.

Comment: -1 not enough jQuery