# How can I get a "divide by" symbol with \usepackage{physics}?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, physics

I usually use `\div` to generate a divide-by symbol, but when using the `physics` package, `\div` gives a nabla followed by a dot ("period") instead.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to produce this division symbol? ÷](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108035/is-there-a-way-to-produce-this-division-symbol-%C3%B7)

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  some of us would like to test this, so if you can provide a compilable example that demonstrates the problem, it will be easier to help.

Comment: note: `amsmath` symbol ÷ renamed `\divisionsymbol`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{physics} \begin{document} $\div$ \end{document}` produces the anomaly.

Comment: @Mico anomaly? I think this is pretty much expected and easy to fix.

Comment: @Mico Package `physics` uses `\div` to typeset the divergence. The `amsmath` symbol ÷ is renamed to `\divisionsymbol`. `$\div{a}$`

Comment: @Mico yes, that example produces the same thing I'm seeing - that the physics package changes the output of \div.

Comment: @Johannes_B that renaming fixes the problem.  I could not find anywhere that the symbol was renamed - almost all references list it as \div.  Thank you!

Comment: If `physics` seems to be the cause of the problem, have a look at the documentation of it. Searc for `\div` and you will find my first comment. ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B - Ah, sorry: I got confused by the `amsmath` reference in your earlier comments (as the issue arises with or without the `amsmath` package having been loaded).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, one should be able to store a symbol before it is overwritten by a package like in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\olddiv\div
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

$\div \quad \olddiv \quad \divisionsymbol$

\end{document}
```

Specific to [`physics`](http://ctan.org/pkg/physics), the package already does this using the macro `\divisionsymbol`.

Comment: The package already stores the symbol in `\divisionsymbol`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I've updated my post to reflect a more general setting and referenced `\divisionsymbol`.