# How does LaTeX renders a \div?

Tags: macros

This is a follow-up question to this one: [How can I get a "divide by" symbol with \usepackage{physics}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313354/how-can-i-get-a-divide-by-symbol-with-usepackagephysics) In the referenced question the OP asked how to `\undef` a redefined `\div`. I want to reinvent the wheel, and see the *exact* "source code" what is used to render `\div` in the first place. But where do I find it?

Here is a MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
What is the \emph{exact} ``source code'' of
\ttfamily\textbackslash div\normalfont, and
where do I find it? Whatever it is, it renders
this: $\div$. I want to use it as a 
starting-point to \ttfamily\textbackslash
def \normalfont my own variant 
\ttfamily\textbackslash mydiv\normalfont.
\end{document}
```

Bonus question: how do I write `\ttfamily \textbackslash` (the MNWE above gives me a warning about "font shapes not available").

Comment: Try `\show\div`

Comment: At least for you MNWE, you can get the ttfamily backslash with `\verb|\def|`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming TeX Live on a Unix system with `bash`, open a terminal window and type

```
texdef -t latex div
```

and return. You'll get the following info:

```bsh
> texdef -t latex div

\div:
\mathchar"2204


\the\div:
8708
```

that's not really so much interesting, perhaps, for the *non cognoscenti*. The same information would be issued by doing `\show\div` in an interactive session or by typing

```
\texttt{\meaning\div}
```

in a document and typesetting it.

However, being `\div` a core math symbol, the real definition can be found in `fontmath.ltx`; type

```
grep '\\div\b' $(kpsewhich fontmath.ltx)
```

and the terminal will print

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\div}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"04}
```

which is indeed the definition the LaTeX kernel does of `\div`.

You find all the core math symbols definitions by doing something like

```
less $(kpsewhich fontmath.ltx)
```

Comment: *all* the math symbol definitions?  no, only the "basic" ones that came with the original tex.  there are a lot more in, e.g., `amsfonts` and `amssymb` and other "add-on" symbol packages.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I added ”core“; it's generally complicated to find the definitions for other symbols. The ”comprehensive list“ helps in finding the package involved, but then it may make rather cryptic definitions.

Comment: thanks for update.  i agree with everything else.  (and having had to track down lots of symbol definitions, because they're not necessarily the same with different fonts, i definitely sympathize with anyone else who has to do it.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The best is `MnSymbol`, where the slot numbers are implicit and you have to count lines.

Comment: `mathabx` is only a little above that; with three fonts, it takes a little digging to figure out which one is relevant.  but you're right about `MnSymbol`.

Answer (score 2):

The OP states that "I want to reinvent the wheel..."

I would note that, to make your own personal version of `\div`, one does not necessarily have to know the exact formulation of the original.  In particular, the code

```
\let\svdiv\div
\def\div{...\svdiv...}
```

will allow a new `\div` to be defined in terms of the original.  Furthermore, in the case of `\div`, as Joseph noted in a comment, `\show\div` reveals the definition as `\mathchar"2204` indicating there is no "code" *per se* for the division sign, but rather it merely points to a glyph slot of the font intself (slot 4 of the math symbol font).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
Here is the new \textbackslash div:
\let\svdiv\div
\def\div{\mathbin{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{.002ex}{c}{-.06ex}{\circ}{\svdiv}}}}
$A \div B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one did not wish to redefine the original, but only to define `\mydiv` in terms of the original, then this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
Here is \textbackslash mydiv:
\def\mydiv{\mathbin{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{.002ex}{c}{-.06ex}{\circ}{\div}}}}
$A \mydiv B$
\end{document}
```